# How to find the maximum value double in an array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, max, double

I'm building a calculator to get a price for a medical marijuana dispensary. There is a 16 percent tax on all sales, as well as a price break at certain weights. My goal is to find a weight to sell at the best price point for the customer, given tax and the break. Im down to just trying to get the highest value of a list of doubles, to compare to the breakpoint array to see if they meet the certain threshold for the breakpoint. I literally just cant seem to get the maximum double in the `weightList` array. Here is my code. My doubles `gramPrice`, `eighthPrice`, etc are the price/gram at a given breakpoint. The `gramWeight`, `eighthWeight,` etc are the weight of product calculated to recieve at that breakpoint. Kinda sloppy terminology I guess, but how can I find the maximum value of my double array?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("##.##");
        
        int desiredPrice = 0 , pricePoint = 0;
        int fivePerGram[] = {5, 15, 25, 50, 100};
        int eightPerGram[] = {8, 25, 45, 90, 160};
        double weightFormat[] = {1, 3.5, 7, 14, 28};
        
        System.out.print("Enter Desired Amount OTD: ");
        if(reader.hasNextInt() == true) {
            desiredPrice = reader.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.print("Enter Price Point (3, 5, 8, 10, 12): " );
        if(reader.hasNextInt() == true) {
            pricePoint = reader.nextInt();
        }
        
        if(pricePoint == 8) {
            double gramPrice = (eightPerGram[0]/1)*1.16;gramPrice = Double.parseDouble(df.format(gramPrice));
            double eighthPrice = (eightPerGram[1]/3.5)*1.16;eighthPrice = Double.parseDouble(df.format(eighthPrice));
            double quarterPrice = (eightPerGram[2]/7)*1.16;quarterPrice = Double.parseDouble(df.format(quarterPrice));
            double halfPrice = (eightPerGram[3]/14)*1.16;halfPrice = Double.parseDouble(df.format(halfPrice));
            double ouncePrice = (eightPerGram[4]/28)*1.16;ouncePrice = Double.parseDouble(df.format(ouncePrice));
            
            double gramWeight = desiredPrice/gramPrice;gramWeight = Double.parseDouble(df.format(gramWeight));
            double eighthWeight = desiredPrice/eighthPrice;eighthWeight = Double.parseDouble(df.format(eighthWeight));
            double quarterWeight = desiredPrice/quarterPrice;quarterWeight = Double.parseDouble(df.format(quarterWeight));
            double halfWeight = desiredPrice/halfPrice;halfWeight = Double.parseDouble(df.format(halfWeight));
            double ounceWeight = desiredPrice/ouncePrice;ounceWeight = Double.parseDouble(df.format(ounceWeight));
            
            double weightList[] = {gramWeight, eighthWeight, quarterWeight, halfWeight, ounceWeight};

            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: Im sorry, was wondering how to get the maximum value of my array of doubles, without losing my decimal format ie not going to ints

Comment: Eh? Getting the maximum value is just a linear scan through the array. Decimal places have nothing to do with it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Provide details as edits to your Question, not by posting Comments. Also, when posting, trim down your example code to the bare minimum needed to illustrate the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note quite sure I got what you're trying to do. If you want the highest value in your `weightList` array, simply do the following.

### With Standard Java 8+

```
final double maxWeight = Arrays.stream(weightList).max().getAsDouble();
```

### With Other Libraries

#### Apache Commons Lang3's [`NumberUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/math/NumberUtils.html#max-double...-)

```
final double maxWeight = NumberUtils.max(weightList);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! havnt used the arrays util much but this is much simpler than anything I had thought of.

Comment: Well, I have to say this felt a bit like a homework question, in which case I'd also recommend to also try to simply implement that logic with your own for-loop and an aggregator to see how it's done. But for production code I guess I'd use the above (or a methode from Apache Commons Collections, or other similar libraries that provide alternatives)